# ORACLE LIVE SQL IMPORT CSV DATA (live oracle sql)

Tags: oracle, csv

Am working on the oracle live sql(provided online) is their a way i can import csv to this online platform and if so , can you please provide a step by step way of doing it. i have  been searching online for a solution but cannot find any link to the oracle online platform   [oracle live](https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/f?p=590:300:1804064832565::NO:::). Thank you .

Comment: @KaushikNayak You did not understand the question and you have already down voted it . am asking how to import from my local machine to the platform , understand before you answer please and remove the down vote

Comment: How did you assume that I downvoted you. I just commented.Thats it.

Comment: @KaushikNayak sorry for that do you have an answer for this please

Comment: I don't know. As an alternative I suggest you use this link to convert CSV to ddl.Then run the ddls in your live sql

Comment: Here's the link. http://www.convertcsv.com/csv-to-sql.htm . I think sqlfiddle too has such options but I never get to work it correctly.

Comment: @KaushikNayak Thanks alot , you should provide this as an answer

Answer (score 3):

I am not aware of any such option available in `Livesql`. There are various other options to accomplish this.

**CSV TO SQL Converter**

http://www.convertcsv.com/csv-to-sql.htm

You can use this tool  to convert CSV to SQL statements. You can choose a csv file from your local machine or an URL.There are various options to change the datatype, constraints (`NOT NULL` etc ).You can create `DML`s for `delete,insert,update,select`.

**SQLFIDDLE:**

http://sqlfiddle.com/ 
In this website, you have an option "*Text to DDL*" .You can simply enter the text from a `csv` file  and it will created the `DDL` to create and populate data in a table.

Use the DDLs, DMLs to *livesql* when you need to run them in Oracle 12c. Otherwise many other sql query execution tools are available online.

Comment: I tried the convertcsv.com tool, and it doesn't convert to Oracle's 12c SQL, which is what Live SQL uses. The left out the semicolons at the end of each statement, which is not a big deal if you don't have a lot of statements, but you have an insert statement for each row and might have thousands of rows. Using the tool's more advanced options for data formatting and whatnot might create further incompatible language as well.

Comment: I also tried the sqlfiddle.com tool. You can choose your SQL version, but the only Oracle version it offers is 11g, and that produced errors for me. I'm not sure what the errors were, and there was no error code, just "Error:".